# How to open dump file with windbg by double clicking in file explorer?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer, double-click, windbg

I am sure I was able to double click a crash dump file (*.dmp) file in explorer in my old PC and it will open up in WinDbg. In my new PC it doesn't open and gives an error.

> Could not create process "c:\my-path\my-crash.exe.dmp". Win32 eror 0x193
>
> %1 is not a valid Win32 application

The error is understandable because it is trying to open the dump file as executable. I need to provide `-z` flag to windbg to tell it to open it as dump file and I also need to enclose the file path in quotes. I have verified this on command line but how do I configure the double click to do that?

Again I am pretty sure I had this working on old PC that I no longer have.

Comment: You need to assoicate the .dmp file extension with windbg.  I do not recomend you do that because windbg supports command line arguments.  Its not designed to be associate with a file extension.

Comment: @Ramhound I have done that, thats why it opens the dmp file but gives that error because of the reasons you described. But I know I had it working in the past, dont know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Richards [explained this in his blog, some years ago](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrew_richards/2011/05/05/windbg-file-association-and-explorer-context-menu/). Open cmd in your install folder of Windbg and run `WinDbg.exe -IA` to register the file File Association. You can also use the provided reg file, but here you need to change the paths.

Comment: That did the trick but like the first comment on that post, I saw it was still not working when I ran windbg -IA because I had already manually associated .dmp file with windbg. I had to remove that by deleting the key below in registry editor and that fixed everything! HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\‌​Explorer\FileExts\.d‌​mp

Comment: It is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.